# I can't modify a created job

Tags: oracle11g, scheduled-tasks, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, job-scheduling

I want to modify a job that I created. but I get 'A database object was specified that does not exist' at the level of  name => 'jb_do'

```
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute (
       name => 'jb_do',
       attribute => 'JOB_ACTION',
       value=> 'myProcedure');
END ;
```

EDIT :

How I created my job

```
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => '"nol"."ts"',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => '',
        number_of_arguments => 0,
        start_date => NULL,
        repeat_interval => NULL,
        end_date => NULL,
        job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
        enabled => false,
        auto_drop => true,
        comments => NULL,
        credential_name => NULL,
        destination_name => NULL);
END;
```

select * from all_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'ts'; returns following

[image]

Comment: What does the `select * from all_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'JB_DO';` query say?

Comment: @nop77svk it gives me the row of that job

Comment: Post the query result here (somehow), please.

Comment: It says the job_name is `'ts'`. How can this be the result of my query, which contains the predicate of `job_name = 'JB_DO'` ?

Comment: @nop77svk I dropped my 'JB_DO' and created a new job 'ts' to see if the problem was due to the job. Of course I modified query to select * from all_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'ts';

Comment: Oh dear. :-/ Don't! I need to see the contents of the `all_scheduler_jobs` exactly for the job you created.

Comment: Also, please, post here the exact PLSQL block by which you created the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the query result screenshot you posted in your question, it appears that you (somehow) managed to create your job with lowercase name. So, the correct way of setting its attributes is:

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute (
        name => '"jb_do"',
        attribute => 'JOB_ACTION',
        value=> 'myProcedure');
END ;
```

... or in case of the `ts` job ...

```
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute (
        name => '"nol"."ts"',
        attribute => 'JOB_ACTION',
        value=> 'myProcedure');
END ;
```

Explanation: Scheduler jobs are considered regular schema objects, therefore the usual naming resolution rules apply to them.